# Eclipse has JRE missing

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed JDK 9,JRE 9.

And I tried install Eclipse, but it told me that *JRE Missing*.

Because it needs JRE, JDK version 8.

So I installed JDK 8 and JRE 8, then the eclipse start install.

How can i use the eclipse on only version 9?

How can i install that without version 8?

Comment: Eclipse mars suports java 9 but this is beta. So use jdk 8

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run Eclipse with Java 9 you need at least Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) which also runs on Java 8.

If you want to **install multiple Eclipse** packages, the **Eclipse installer** saves disk space.

For a **single Eclipse installation** you can also use [**one of the packages** which you can download as ZIP archive](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/).

For 64 bit Java you have to choose the 64 bit Eclipse version, for 32 bit Java you have to choose the 32 bit Eclipse (even if your operating system is 64 bit).

The JRE which is used to run Eclipse (or to run the Eclipse Installer) can be specified in the [`eclipse.ini`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) file. The JREs that are used to run your application have to be set in *Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs*.